# How do I delay materialisation of an akka stream that's being appended to another akka stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

The documentation for [`FlowOps#concat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.6/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html#concat[U>:Out,Mat2](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[U],Mat2]):FlowOps.this.Repr[U]) states that

> ... the Source is materialized together with this Flow and just kept from producing elements by asserting back-pressure until its time comes.

In other words, if I have

```
sourceA.concat(sourceB)
```

then `sourceB` will be materialised at the same time as `sourceA`.

How do I delay `sourceB` being materialised until `sourceA` has completed?

I'm using Akka 2.5.6.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why you want to do this?  Since streams return futures could you wait for the future to finish and then start the next stream?

Comment: The Sources I'm concatenating are database queries. I've started getting (currently) unexplained database timeouts on these queries. I'd like to eliminate the possibility that hitting the database with so many queries in parallel is contributing to the problem. (I'd be surprised if it was. But I don't have a lot to go on, so I'm at the stage of eliminating possibilities.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `Source.lazily()`?

Here's what its scala doc says:

> Creates a `Source` that is not materialized until there is downstream demand, when the source gets materialized the materialized future is completed with its value, if downstream cancels or fails without any demand the create factory is never called and the materialized `Future` is failed.

See also: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#lazily

That is:

```
sourceA.concat(Source.lazily(() => sourceB))
```

Comment: The problem is that concat surprisingly enough is eager, and asks for the first element from the concatenated source right away, which also triggers the lazy source right away, there is an issue tracking this: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23044